# Swift difference between Value: and Value ==

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

I was looking through some open-source libraries like ReactiveCocoa and Alamofire and I noticed this syntax inside `Signal.swift` (ReactiveCocoa):

```
extension SignalType where Value: SignalProducerType, Error == Value.Error
```

I know that `Value: SignalProducerType` adds constraints to the generic or associated type `Value`, either class or protocol constraints. But what's the difference between `Value: SignalProducerType` and using `==`?

For the following contrived example:

```
protocol Test {
    typealias Value
}

extension Test where Value: NSObject, Value == NSError {

}
```

how is that different from

```
extension Test where Value: NSObject, Value: NSError {

}
```

Both of those examples compile.

And extending on that, can you do that with `Self`? Something like:

```
extension Test where Self: SomeClass, Self == NSError
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing

```
extension Test where Value: NSObject, Value == NSError {

}
```

your are making the extension available to types that conform to `Test` and have **Value equals to NSError**.

On the other hand with

```
extension Test where Value: NSObject, Value: NSError {

}
```

the extension is available when a class conform to Test and the type of Value is NSError or a subclass.

### Example

The following code does compile

```
protocol Test {
    typealias Value
}

extension Test where Value: NSObject, Value : NSError {
    func foo() { }
}

class MyError: NSError {}

class A: Test {
    typealias Value = MyError
}

A().foo()
```

But if we replace the `:` in your extension condition with `=` like this

```
extension Test where Value: NSObject, Value = NSError {
    func foo() { print("foo") }
}
```

the code no longer compile.